# Top level media queries with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm currently in the process of migrating from plain SCSS/SASS to styled-components.

However, I was wondering if there's any way to add "top-level" media queries. Here's what I'm talking about:

```css
/* Large screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    top: 0;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100vh;

    &:hover {
      width: 16rem;

      .link-text {
        display: inline;
      }

      .logo svg {
        margin-left: 11rem;
      }

      .logo-text {
        left: 0px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using styled-components, it seems like I would need to copy the "top-level" media queries inside each component, but that seems ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually create a global style for media. There I put my top level media queries.

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

export default createGlobalStyle`
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        outline: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

  @media(max-width: 800px) {
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
  }

`;
```